# FindObjectsOfType saying the name doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an mod menu for a game called Ravenfield. It's an injectable DLL. I need to modify some things about the player, for example the speed, health, etc etc and for that I need to find the player object which contains all of that. With dnSpy I was able to find the player class which is called "Actor".
When I try to find it in `public void Start()` by typing `Player = FindObjectsOfType<Actor>();` it says "The name "Player" does not exist in the current context.". I've added both UnityEngine.dll and Assembly-CSharp to my refrences.

I haven't slept very well and I'm sort of braindead ATM so if anyone could help me with this, I'd appreciate it very much. :)

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Ravenhack
{
    class Main : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            Player = FindObjectOfType<Actor>();
        }
        public void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F4))
            {
                Player.SetHealth(100f); //FindObjectOfType<Actor>().SetHealth(100f);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Delete))
            {
                Loader.Unload();
            }
        }
        public void OnGUI()
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 350f, 550f), "RAVENHACK 1.1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't have a property or field named `Player`.

Comment: @DanielA.White How do I make it a property? I'm just starting off, pretty noob at these kinds of stuff.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Above your `Start` method, you probably need a line like `private Player Player;` Though common C# best practice means you should probably name that variable `_player` to distinguish it from the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the class you defined or the class you inherit from (`MonoBehaviour`) has a property or field named Player.

The least you need to make your class work is the line below:

`private Actor Player { get; set; }`

But you should read more about these topics: C# properties, accessibility and encapsulation

Comment: Well it got rid of the error but still doesn't actually set the health float to a 100.

Comment: Because you didn't program that part yet. Are you following a tutorial? Are you sure you have all the right resources?

Comment: Without knowing more about the code of the game I can't help you any further, sorry.